# How do I show reference count in Visual Studio Code?

Tags: visual-studio-code

I want to show references count in Visual Studio Code. How can I do it?

[image]

Comment: Just a note to those using VS Community edition - this feature is not available.

Comment: CodeLens is available in VS2019 community edition.

Answer (score 140, accepted):

This feature is called CodeLens.

In Visual Studio find it in menu *Options* → *Text Editor* → *All languages* → *CodeLens*.

And in Visual Studio Code it is in menu *File* → *Preferences* → *Settings* → "editor.codeLens": true

Comment: I cannot find anything about codelens on mac version. Am I missing an extension?

Comment: @savante try searching in Settings --> User/Workspace for codelens

Comment: In VSCode v1.40.0, search settings for `codeLens` and check out the `TypeScript` section.

Comment: Do you know if there's a way to group by file? Like, if an export is only imported once then it shows "1", rather than the number of times it's used in each file?

Comment: I needed to enable all 3 of these settings;
"editor.codeLens": true,
    "typescript.implementationsCodeLens.enabled": true,
    "typescript.referencesCodeLens.enabled": true,

Comment: Is this available for Python? Even this is enabled, my python code doesn't show the count.

Answer (score 68):

Visual Studio Code version 1.28.2:

You need to add this to *User Settings*:

Menu *File* → *Preferences* → *Settings*:

```
"typescript.referencesCodeLens.enabled": true,
```

Comment: It says "unknown configuration setting"

Answer (score 27):

The menu structure ususally changes during years. 
So in `VSCode` v.1.43 please follow the next steps:

1. Click `Gear icon` and go to `Settings`

[image]

2. In the "`Settings`" window in the input field type "`reference`", click "`User`" tab, under "`Extensions`" click "`Typescript`" and find "`Reference Code Lens`" checkboxes for `javascript/typescript`.

[image]

Checking/unchecking checkboxes will automatically apply your changes.

Comment: Is this available for Python?

Comment: @Koder101 is Python support Typescript?

Comment: VS Code supports Python, and just like other VS code provides this function reference count for C# or typescript, I wanted it for Python too.

Answer (score 12):

The simple process for show the reference count.

1. Step 1: From Settings – Type CodeLens and Enable the Editor: Code Lens and JavaScript > References Code Lens to check the references in JavaScript File.

[image]

2. Step 2: Then open any of your JavaScript file to identify the References of Property or Method in the file.

[image]

- If any case, you can't show the reference, then enable(yes) assets to
  build and debug in own project.

[image]

- If you'll click to the yes button of assets then, you'll seen the .vscode file

[image]

Answer (score 5):

Sometimes you don't want to turn it on/off completely, but toggle it on/off with a keyboard shortcut. If so, the following may help:

1. Install an extension: https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=rebornix.toggle
2. and configure it for your desires. (Preferences -> Keyboard Shortcuts -> `keybindings.json`)

For Example for TypeScript:

```
{
    "key": "F4",
    "command": "toggle",
    "when": "editorTextFocus",
    "args": {
        "id": "myChosenIdWhatEverItIs",
        "value": [
            {
              "typescript.referencesCodeLens.enabled": true,
            },
            {
              "typescript.referencesCodeLens.enabled": false,
            }
        ]
    }
}
```

Comment: Huge thanks for this suggestion! Something like this can/will solve a lot of issues I currently have, as well as solve some I didn't realize I had, lol. This is great.

Answer (score -1):

In Visual Studio 2019 Community it's in Tools → Options → Text Editor → All Languages → CodeLens.

Comment: The OP is asking about **VS Code**, not Visual Studio.

Answer (score -1):

On Visual Studio 2019 Community Edition, just hit Ctrl+Q or look for the text box next to Help, enter CodeLens there. That is by far the quickest and easiest.

[CodeLens on Search Enable](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pmuEp.png)

Comment: The OP is asking about **VS Code**, not Visual Studio.