# How to show number references in functions/class/variables for PHP in Visual Studio Code

Tags: php, visual-studio-code

I used to code in `C#` and I find it really useful to see the number of reference count right above the function. Is there any know extension like this for PHP files?

I have already looked into [How do I show reference count in Visual Studio Code?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45490475/how-do-i-show-reference-count-in-visual-studio-code)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I show reference count in Visual Studio Code?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45490475/how-do-i-show-reference-count-in-visual-studio-code)

Comment: @MarkusZeller already looked into that before posting my question, it doesn't work for PHP. I should have included it in my question body, my bad. thanks for the response.

Comment: I suppose it is not available, yet, as the list of extensions using code lens is still limited to typescript and c#.